# SQL WHERE clause with binary

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a SQL Server database table with a `varbinary(max)` column (i.e. `Data VarBinary(max)` in a `create table` command).

Is it possible to do a `where` clause with some kind of pattern matching within the binary data?

For example, using the C# .NET `SqlCommand` object, I found that I can do a query like `select * from TableName where Data = 0x4638763849838709 go`, where the value is the full data column value.  But I want to be able to pattern match just parts of the data, like `select * from TableName where Data = 0x%3876% go`.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the binary data a representation of a specific document/file type?

Answer (score 15):

For the example you have given in the question

```
WITH t(c) AS
(
SELECT CAST(0x4638763849838709 AS VARBINARY(MAX)) 
)
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE CHARINDEX(0x3876,c) > 0
```

Comment: This works well when you know a specific continuous range of hex characters to search for. It worked for my particular case.

Comment: This was the exact case I am looking for. I have the encoded binary value which cannot be decoded but I need to search in DB using this value.

Comment: But, how do we do this along with PreparedStatements?

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server doesn't provide any functions to search through `VARBINARY` fields, so this is not possible.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318906/how-to-search-a-varbinary-field-in-sql-server) related SO question and answers.

Essentially, you will need to extract the binary information and use a tool that understands the format it is in to search through it. It can't be done directly in SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(max),myvarbinaryfield,2) like '%46387638%'
```

perhaps I should have used the OP's example:

```
select * 
from TableName 
where CONVERT(varchar(max),Data,2) like '%3876%'
```

**Explanation:** The characters 0x aren't added to the left of the converted result for style 2. Please see the Microsoft documentation for converting varbinary data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#binary-styles

Comment: Please add an explanation about how this code answers the question

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I have added an explanation. Good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Taking a shot in the dark here, but you could convert the field to VARCHAR(MAX) first, then compared using a LIKE statement.

E.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), Data) LIKE '%2345%'
```

Comment: This did not work for me because it does try to encode the VARBINARY as string, so I get gibberish instead of a string representation of the hex value. @Martin Smith's answer comes closest to what was asked.